# How do I get the Android app to display something from the website?

Tags: android

this is my first time asking here and I'm new to Android Studio.
How do I get the app to display something from the website ?
I'm learning from the "Connecting to the Network" in Android Studio Training
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html
.I've tried changing the URL but I can't get it to display anything other than my error message
https://i.stack.imgur.com/34TJ8.jpg

edit: If it is possible I would like to try to do it in this way, because I want to know where did I do wrong here and also try to solve it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "HttpExample";
    private TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Connected to network", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



private  String downloadURL(String myurl) throws IOException{
    InputStream is = null;

    try{
        URL url = new URL(myurl);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);

        conn.connect();
        int response = conn.getResponseCode();
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "The response is: " + response);
        is = conn.getInputStream();

        String contentAsString = readIt(is);
        return contentAsString;
    }finally {
        if(is != null){
            is.close();
        }
    }
}
private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls){
        try{
            return downloadURL(urls[0]);
        }catch (IOException e){
            return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
        textView.setText(result);
    }
}
public String readIt (InputStream is)throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    BufferedReader reader =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    String input;
    while ((input = reader.readLine()) != null)
        builder.append(input);

    return builder.toString();
}

public void myClickHandler (View view){
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()){
        Snackbar.make(view, "Connected to network", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();
        new DownloadWebPageTask().execute("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.fullcreamlowfat.wirelessp5q1.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<TextView android:id="@+id/display"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:onClick="myClickHandler"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You could log the exception in addition to returning a string stating "unable to retrieve". Then you'd know the actual problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a misunderstanding regarding what the tutorial is trying to say. The tutorial page shows a way to download files from the internet in a background process since all events needn't be shown to the user.

Say for example, you are making a **cricket live score** app and you need to get the **scores from your website**. Now you don't provide the web page URL for the scores data to the user and ask him to view it using Chrome, Firefox or other web browsers right?

Hence, you would **download that live score data within the app** using the `HttpURLConnection` and would make use of `AsyncTask` method for keeping this task off the main thread of the app. You might also show a Dialog Box which says "Please wait..." to inform the user about this. **THIS IS CASE 1**

Or do you want to ***embed*** the Web Browser for directly showing the data as-is within the app. **THIS IS CASE 2**

Here, the tutorial is trying to accomplish a case 1 scenario whereas the answers provided by @Ramesh and @Fahad Shah provide case 2.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to do the CASE 1.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in xml

```
<WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView" />
```

in java activity

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("your web link");
        webView.clearCache(true);

        //If you will not use this method url links are opeen in new brower not in webview
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        //Show loader on url load
        public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {
            if (progressDialog == null) {
                // in standard case YourActivity.this
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(fixture.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progressDialog.show();
            }
        }
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            try{
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    progressDialog = null;
                }
            }catch(Exception exception){
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }); webView.loadUrl(url);
```

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in Manifest

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebView to display HTML content or load Url Directly.

```
   webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
   webView.loadData(YOUR_HTML, "text/html", "UTF-8"); // which you got from response
```

or

```
webView.loadUrl(YOUR_URL);
```

Android WebView tutorial.
    http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_webview_layout.htm

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

use in xml

```
<WebView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/webView" />
```

in java activity

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("your web link");
        webView.clearCache(true);
```

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in Manifest

Answer (score 0):

To display content from Web URL you can use **[WebView in Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)** may be your problem is the url you are using is not valid or you haven't done proper implementation please follow steps as written below

In your androidmenifest.xml use this permission to ask connecting internet permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

and then in your XML file use WebView component

```
<WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/web" />
```

and from java side,

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("your web link");
```

Use [this Link](https://gist.github.com/TapanHp/1262de5a169c42d6918c2b63c72e09e0) i have made a pretty nice code snippet it will definitely help you.